# ActivityToLaunch cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, shortcut

Now I would like to make shortcut, so my code is

```
    ShortcutIconResource icon = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, R.drawable.icon);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    Intent launchIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityToLaunch.class);

    intent.putExtra( Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, launchIntent );
    intent.putExtra( Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, /*someNickname()*/"" );
    intent.putExtra( Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, icon );   
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```

But I got this error message.

ActivityToLaunch cannot be resolved to a type

In stackoverflow, I saw many codes such as

```
Intent launchIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityToLaunch.class);
```

What's the matter?

My project uses android sdk version 2.2, and imports

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Intent.ShortcutIconResource;
import android.os.Bundle;
```

My manifest.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.my.mytest"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<activity android:name=".ShortCutActivity" android:label="@string/shortcut_label">  

       <intent-filter>  
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT" />     
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />   
       </intent-filter> 
</activity>
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".TestActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

and apkname is  and com.my.mytest.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Please share the manifest file and the apk packagename, java package name

Comment: @Rajdeep DuaI added the information you needed. please recheck and help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `ActivityToLaunch` actual name of your activity? Because according to your manifest what you need is probably

```
Intent launchIntent = new Intent(this, ShortCutActivity.class);
```

or

```
Intent launchIntent = new Intent(this, TestActivity.class);
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. That's right!!! I fell in panic myself. I misunderstood the word <ActivityToLaunch> as the Java&Android KeyWord...ggg

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to import the class:

```
import package.name.ActivityToLaunch;
```

In Eclipse type Ctrl+Shift+O to automatically import the class. If that fails, check your spelling.

Comment: Excuse me, I did it but i got <Syntax error on token "package", Identifier expected> I'm a beginner for android. Please tell me in details.

Answer (score 0):

ActivityToLaunch.class is not defined in the Manifest file. 
As Vladmir pointed out you need to enter a valid class for Activity.